# Flutter cant find android SDK even tho correct path and latest android studio version

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I try to debug an android app on my physical device. i could yesterday but today my device wont show up in devices i ran flutter doctor see this error.

Android SDK file not found: adb.

i already tried update the path and check the path it seems normal. i never changed any of the developer settings of my phone (usb debug etc.)

```
    • Flutter version 1.7.8+hotfix.4 at C:\src\flutter_windows_v1.7.8+hotfix.4-stable\flutter
    • Framework revision 20e59316b8 (3 weeks ago), 2019-07-18 20:04:33 -0700
    • Engine revision fee001c93f
    • Dart version 2.4.0

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Emirhan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    X Android SDK file not found: adb.
    • Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
      visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 38.2.1
    • Dart plugin version 183.6270
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.37.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Emirhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.3.0

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

Comment: Check if ``C:\Users\Emirhan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\`` is on your path variable, so that adb can be run (try running ``adb`` in a terminal).

Comment: i added platform tools to enviroment path variable and run adb it didnt recognize the command. i tried changing directory and run adb it didnt recognize either. i realized there is no adb.exe in my computer could this be the error?

Comment: Yes, adb.exe should exist in platform-tools folder.

Comment: i downloaded adb.exe and licensed it Android SDK file not found: adb. error solved. but now i cant authorize my phone in any way. i run flutter devices and see this `List of devices attached
52002c985efc25fb        unauthorized`

Answer (score 0):

I also added all environment path variable that showed me  [android SDK not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81JvZ.jpg). Then finally I went to `android studio=>Tools=>SDK manager` and install or update the SDK version.
`C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`  This might help to newbie.